# getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);

Tags: android

```
restartLoader(0, data, this);
```

while using `restartLoader` like above I got an error:

> The method `restartLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks)` in the type  `LoaderManager` is not applicable for the `arguments (int, Bundle, MainActivity)`.

Here is my code:

```
    private void doSearch(String query){
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);
    }

    private void getPlace(String query){
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, data, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your MainActivity is not implementing `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` try this:

```
 class MainActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>
```

do not forget to `import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`

Comment: @WaqasYousaf Did you try this?